Slice row out of CSV file using either Python alone or jsonata
I am using the C2Intel Feeds to find specific observables and when I do, I'd like to extract/slice out the row.
Example:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drb-ra/C2IntelFeeds/master/feeds/domainC2swithURLwithIP-filter-abused.csv
If you go to the link/CSV file, I am able to find a specific IP, i.e. - 54.161.191.72.
I would like to slice out the whole row:
www.e-enroll-benefits.com,Possible Cobalt Strike C2 Domain,/enrollmentinfo/,54.161.191.72
Since each row is different, I'm not sure how I would go about doing this process.  I thought about finding the length but I'm not sure how to do it since it varies.
Here's my current code:
ip_address = "54.161.191.72"
lines = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drb-ra/C2IntelFeeds/master/feeds/domainC2swithURLwithIP-filter-abused.csv"
for line in lines:
    if re.match("ip_address", line):
        values_slice = line.split(": ")[-1]#not sure how you get the whole row?

Appreciate any help or guidance. Thanks in advance!

I suggest printing out each "line" variable. This isn't doing what you want.. Since there's no file being downloaded. lines is just a one line string, and so you're iterating over characters of that string

I tried with simpler approach and it works for me.
Instead of visiting the url, I downloaded the csv file to a local folder, ideally the same folder where the python script is run to save the 'os.chdir' step.
Please see below:
import os
os.chdir('/Users/***/***/') # please update this path to where your csv file downloaded is
ip_address = '54.161.191.72'
lines = open('domainC2swithURLwithIP-filter-abused.csv')
for line in lines:
    if ip_address in line:
        print(line)

Below is the output I got:

Happy to answer any questions that you may have. Cheers!

This process was great, I was able to use this structure updated a couple of variables.  Works perfect!  Thx

Thanks for sharing and I am glad it helped!

Not entirely sure what you mean by "slice row out" so I'm going to assume you just want to find a line (row) that has a particular value.
Your data are CSV format so why not utilise the built-in csv module? After all, that's what it's there for.
Try this:
import csv
import requests

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drb-ra/C2IntelFeeds/master/feeds/domainC2swithURLwithIP-filter-abused.csv"
ip = "54.161.191.72"

with requests.get(url) as response:
    response.raise_for_status() # check HTTP response
    lines = response.text.splitlines()[1:] # split text (CSV) response into lines skipping the first row (column headings)
    reader = csv.reader(lines) # construct the reader 
    for i, row in enumerate(reader): # enumerate the reader
        if row[-1] == ip: # check last column
            print(lines[i])
            break

Output:
www.e-enroll-benefits.com,Possible Cobalt Strike C2 Domain,/enrollmentinfo/,54.161.191.72


Your code is not fetching the file before using it. Also, you already have the whole row in line, you just have to print it.
Here is an updated version that fetches the link each time and prints line containing the given IP address.
import requests

URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drb-ra/C2IntelFeeds/master/feeds/domainC2swithURLwithIP-filter-abused.csv"
ip_address = "54.161.191.72"

c2list = requests.get(URL).text
for line in c2list.split("\n"):
    if ip_address in line:
        print(line)

This code splits the response into lines and checks every line for the specified IP address.
RegEx is not necessary to just filter out a row.
Use if re.search(<regex_string>, line): when more advanced pattern matching is needed.
I hope this has solved your problem!

Thanks for this iteration, I did use parts to make my final version.  Cheers
